# Need to Sum based on ID

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I have different tables in different excel sheets and there is a key value exists in all tables (Employee ID) , I need to sum elements in different sheets based on Employee id

```
Sheet 1                       Sheet 2

A   B                          A    B             
ID  Value                      ID   Value
1    100                       1    500
```

I need to sum  100+500 based since it is same employee ID 1

Comment: Do you have or want to display the result in a separate table where you have only the unique IDs and the sum to be calculated? Do IDs repeat in the same table?

Comment: I will clarify it more:

Comment: Please find the below link for a sample of data for clarity : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8t0qDYyzyMuT1NOQ0pzWXVOTms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What I posted should give you what you need. Have you tested the answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the `sumif` function. `SUMIF(Range, Criteris, [sum range])`

The formula could could look like this:
`=SUMIF(Sheet2!A3:B5,Sheet1!A3,Sheet2!B3:B5)+B3`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As pat2015 says, there are a few questions that needs to be answered before a proper answer can be given.

If the IDs don't repeat, and you just want to display the sum in a cell, you can do a simple `vlookup` for every table. 
Say you put the ID you want to look up in cell A1 and then you put the following where you want the sum to appear:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(A1,Table1,2,0),VLOOKUP(A1,Table2,2,0))
```

And complete for every table.

```
Sheet1!Table1
```

Does not have to be used, since excel will find the table anyway. But will be needed for a absolute reference.

If you have multiple entries of the same ID in a single table, they will be missed. 

<strike>If you want to catch them as well, I'd suggest using VBA instead. If that works for you.</strike>

*edit*

If you have, or might have, multiple entries of the same ID in a single table, the suggested `sumif` works well.
Two examples for three tables.

```
=SUM(SUMIF(Table1[ID],A1,Table1[Value]),SUMIF(Table2[ID],A1,Table2[Value]),SUMIF(Table3[ID],A1,Table3[Value]))
```

or just add sumifs together

```
=SUMIF(Table1[ID],A1,Table1[Value])+SUMIF(Table2[ID],A1,Table2[Value])+SUMIF(Table3[ID],A1,Table3[Value])
```

You can use the entire table as range, but it's better to specify which column you want to search. If you have multiple columns and the value you are searching for is present in other columns as well, there might be some strange results.

**New combined solution with your example.**

I used a macro to collect all the IDs and then populate a table in the result sheet. The code looks like this:

```
    Sub CollectIDs()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim K As Long, ar
    K = 1
    For Each ar In Array("A", "G", "K")
        For i = 1 To 10000
            If Worksheets("Building-1").Cells(i, ar).Value <> "" Then
                If IsNumeric(Worksheets("Building-1").Cells(i, ar).Value) Then
                    Worksheets("Result").Cells(K + 1, "A").Value = Worksheets("Building-1").Cells(i, ar).Value
                    K = K + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next ar

    For Each ar In Array("A", "I")
        For i = 1 To 10000
            If Worksheets("Building-2").Cells(i, ar).Value <> "" Then
                If IsNumeric(Worksheets("Building-2").Cells(i, ar).Value) Then
                    Worksheets("Result").Cells(K + 1, "A").Value = Worksheets("Building-2").Cells(i, ar).Value
                    K = K + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next ar
    Worksheets("Result").Range("Table1").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

For changes in the code to adapt to the document, edit Worksheet names to fit changes, and edit the Arrays to fit the column containing IDs.
*Please don't put any other numbers in those columns, as the code will pick them up as an ID.*

Then, in the result table, the value column contains the code:

```
=SUMIF(Table2[ID];A2;Table2[Value]) + SUMIF(Table3[ID];A2;Table3[Value]) + SUMIF(Table4[ID];A2;Table4[Value])+ SUMIF(Table5[ID];A2;Table5[Value]) + SUMIF(Table6[ID];A2;Table6[Value])
```

That is one `SUMIF` for every table.        *Make sure that this is containing the right names for all the tables, or if you are using ranges, the right ranges of course.*

**Please note!**

**My language settings forces me to use semicolon (;) isntead of commas(,) in the function. Change this to fit your settings.**

Here is my example, hope it suits your needs.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_8icTMsheWfcXpwc0NLOGJvdmc

Comment: I would like to thank you a lot for your answer,

Comment: Please find the below link for more clarity , please note that the tables where the ID and value are repeated in same sheet and other sheets also

Comment: Please note that the tables are repeated in the same sheet and other sheets also 
The ID is repeated in the ID Columns, and ID not have a master or list for the all IDs without repeating.
Each sheet is representing a building and have many tables for Id and value, IDs might be exist in a table and not exist in the other 
So we need to have all IDs in a separated sheets without duplicates by formula if possible and calculate the sum for each ID in all tables in all sheets.

Comment: Please check the below link as sample of data for clarity 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8t0qDYyzyMuT1NOQ0pzWXVOTms/view?usp=sharing
Please you can update and upload and provide a link if possible

Comment: The easiest way to collect all the Unique IDs I think is with VBA. 
If this is not acceptable, it's almost easier to just manually copy all IDs into the result list, and then use the "Remove duplicates" function.
I'll write a VBA that does exactly that.